# move files from one directory to another based on a specific line

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

I have some text files in a directory. I would like to read all the files in this directory  and if the file has the following line

`SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY`  move that file with its all contents to another directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `find` and `grep`:

```
$ find . -type f -exec \
  fgrep -l "SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY" {} \; \
  | xargs -i%  mv % /path/to/new/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in bash:

```
grep -l "PATTERN" *
```

gives you a list of files that contains PATTERN in current directory. So unless you have too many files you could do:

```
mv `grep -l "SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY"` /another/directory
```

The back ticks (they are no normal quotes) executes the command and replaces it with the output (in this case with the list of files). Instead of the back ticks you can use $(command). So you can just as well write:

```
mv $(grep -l "SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY") /another/directory
```

If you have alot of files, bash might not be able to expand that many files (you will reach the limit of how big your command will be...it is alot). You must then resort to xargs:

```
grep -l "SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY" | xargs -i mv {} /another/directory
```

The -i to xargs means that it will take one line at a time from the output from grep (a matching filename) and where the {} are will be expanded to that text and the command will run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python.  The os.path.isdir() was necessary to bypass subdirectories.  The "and file[-3:] != '.py'" is needed if running this .py script from the source directory.  Alternately you could just check for the name of the script if you need to move .py files.

```
import os
import shutil

src = '/source'
dst = '/destination'
pattern = 'SAMPLE 350 AN INTEGER OF TYPE :DECIMAL : CAN BE ASSEMBLED BY'
for file in os.listdir(src):
  if not os.path.isdir(file):
    f = open(file)
    for line in f:
      if pattern in line and file[-3:] != '.py':
        f.close()
        shutil.move(file,dst)
        break
    f.close()
```